# Load Current Assembly into different AppDomain

Tags: c#, .net, appdomain

I have created an `AppDomain` with a different base directory. However, I cannot seem to load the currently executing assembly into the other AppDomain without having a copy of the current executing assembly in the base directory. I've even tried to load it from the bytes.

I get no exception when I try to load, but when I try to use:

```
domain.DoCallBack(new CrossAppDomainDelegate(...
```

I get:

> Could not load file or assembly ........... The system cannot find the file specified.

My code is as follows:

```
private static void SaveAssemblies(Assembly ass, List<byte[]> assemblyByteList)
{
    AssemblyName[] assNames = ass.GetReferencedAssemblies();
    foreach (AssemblyName assName in assNames)
    {
        Assembly referedAss = Assembly.Load(assName);
        if (!referedAss.GlobalAssemblyCache)
        {
            SaveAssemblies(referedAss, assemblyByteList);
        }
    }
    byte[] rawAssembly = File.ReadAllBytes(ass.Location);
    assemblyByteList.Add(rawAssembly);
}

public static AppDomain CreateAppDomain(string dir, string name)
{
    AppDomainSetup domainSetup = new AppDomainSetup();
    domainSetup.ApplicationBase = dir;
    domainSetup.ApplicationName = Path.GetFileName(dir);
    domainSetup.PrivateBinPath = Path.Combine(dir, "Libs");

    AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(name, null, domainSetup);
    //Load system assemblies needed for the module
    List<byte[]> assemblyByteList = new List<byte[]>();
    SaveAssemblies(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), assemblyByteList);

    foreach (byte[] rawAssembly in assemblyByteList)
        domain.Load(rawAssembly);

    domain.DoCallBack(new CrossAppDomainDelegate(SetupLogging));
    return domain;
}
```

Update:

It seems the assembly is loaded if i look in output i see this

'TaskExecuter.Terminal.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'NLog'
'TaskExecuter.Terminal.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'TaskExecuter', Symbols loaded.

but i still get the exception... i don't understand this

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException was unhandled   Message=Could not load
>   file or assembly 'TaskExecuter, Version=1.0.4244.31921,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.   Source=mscorlib
>   FileName=TaskExecuter, Version=1.0.4244.31921, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null   FusionLog==== Pre-bind state information ===
>   LOG: User = Peter-PC\Peter LOG: DisplayName = TaskExecuter,
>   Version=1.0.4244.31921, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null 
>   (Fully-specified) LOG: Appbase =
>   file:///C:/ProgramData/TaskExecuter/TaskLib/uTorrentTasks LOG: Initial
>   PrivatePath = C:\ProgramData\TaskExecuter\TaskLib\uTorrentTasks\Libs
>   Calling assembly : (Unknown).
>   === LOG: This bind starts in default load context. LOG: Using
>   application configuration file: d:\users\peter\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\TaskExecuter\TaskExecuter.Terminal\bin\Release\TaskExecuter.Terminal.vshost.exe.Config
>   LOG: Using host configuration file:  LOG: Using machine configuration
>   file from
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
>   LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private,
>   custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind). LOG: Attempting
>   download of new URL
>   file:///C:/ProgramData/TaskExecuter/TaskLib/uTorrentTasks/TaskExecuter.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/ProgramData/TaskExecuter/TaskLib/uTorrentTasks/TaskExecuter/TaskExecuter.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/ProgramData/TaskExecuter/TaskLib/uTorrentTasks/Libs/TaskExecuter.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/ProgramData/TaskExecuter/TaskLib/uTorrentTasks/Libs/TaskExecuter/TaskExecuter.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/ProgramData/TaskExecuter/TaskLib/uTorrentTasks/TaskExecuter.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/ProgramData/TaskExecuter/TaskLib/uTorrentTasks/TaskExecuter/TaskExecuter.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/ProgramData/TaskExecuter/TaskLib/uTorrentTasks/Libs/TaskExecuter.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/ProgramData/TaskExecuter/TaskLib/uTorrentTasks/Libs/TaskExecuter/TaskExecuter.EXE.
>
> StackTrace:
>          at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName
>   fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly
>   locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound,
>   Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
>          at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName
>   fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly
>   locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound,
>   Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
>          at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName
>   assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark,
>   Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
>          at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String
>   assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark,
>   Boolean forIntrospection)
>          at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString)
>          at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.LoadAssemblyFromString(String
>   assemblyName)
>          at
>   System.Reflection.MemberInfoSerializationHolder..ctor(SerializationInfo
>   info, StreamingContext context)
>          at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate
>   callBackDelegate)
>          at TaskExecuter.AppDomainHelper.CreateAppDomain(String dir,
>   String name) in d:\users\peter\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\TaskExecuter\TaskExecuter\AppDomainHelper.cs:line 50
>          at TaskExecuter.TaskManagment.TaskFinder.Probe() in
>   d:\users\peter\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\TaskExecuter\TaskExecuter\TaskManagment\TaskFinder.cs:line
>   29
>          at TaskExecuter.TaskManagment.TaskManager.LoadTasks() in
>   d:\users\peter\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\TaskExecuter\TaskExecuter\TaskManagment\TaskManager.cs:line
>   63
>          at TaskExecuter.TaskManagment.TaskManager.Start() in
>   d:\users\peter\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\TaskExecuter\TaskExecuter\TaskManagment\TaskManager.cs:line
>   95
>          at TaskExecuter.Terminal.Program.Main(String[] args) in
>   d:\users\peter\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\TaskExecuter\TaskExecuter.Terminal\Program.cs:line 16
>          at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly,
>   String[] args)
>          at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>          at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object
>   state)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   ignoreSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
>   InnerException:

Comment: It is nice practice to not shorten assembly to simple "ass". It could behave nicer if not called as such :).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, just wait until you start building up a stringbuilder to log info about assemblies.. what would you call that variable with that shorthand? (pluginLog, domainLog, typeLog, ___)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was able to recover the linked to blog post using archive.org and also come up with a working solution.

My goal was to dynamically compile an exe into a temporary location, and then have that exe shadow load all main dlls in a child appdomain so that the main application that spawned the exe can be updated easily. The basic approach is using childAppDomain.CreateInstanceFrom to create a type that in the constructor installs the assembly resolve event handler. My code looked like

```
var exportAppDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(
    runnerName,
    null,
    appDomainSetup,
    new PermissionSet(PermissionState.Unrestricted));

exportAppDomain.CreateInstanceFrom(
    Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location,
    "ExportLauncher.AppDomainResolver",
    true,
    BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance,
    null,
    new object[] { Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location },
    null,
    null);
```

And the type that creates the needed AssemblyResolve handler (the blog post below describes why you need another type)

```
class AppDomainResolver
{
    string _sourceExeLocation;

    public AppDomainResolver(string sourceExeLocation)
    {
        _sourceExeLocation = sourceExeLocation;
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve;
    }

    Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Name.Contains("exporterLauncher")) // why does it not already know it has this assembly loaded? the seems to be required
            return typeof(AppDomainResolver).Assembly;
        else
            return null;
    }
}
```

Here is the original blog post:

Application Domains is hard…

Have you ever been working with Application Domain in .NET?, in the beginning it doesn’t seem all that difficult, but ones you get to know them you begin to realize all the little difficulties.

Everything works fine as long as you don’t move outside the Host AppDomains.BaseDirectory, but in our case we wanted to have Plug-ins deployed at say location “C:\My Plug-ins” while the host application would run at “C:\Program Files\My App”, since we might run into dependencies from the AppDomain to some of the Host Assemblies problems was apparently inevitable.

The Classic
Here is some simple code and our first attempt.

```
 1:  string applicationBase = Path.GetDirectoryName(interOperabilityPackageType.AssemblyDescription.AssemblyPath);
   2:  AppDomainSetup setup = new AppDomainSetup
   3:  {
   4:      ApplicationName = name,
   5:      ApplicationBase = applicationBase,
   6:      PrivateBinPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
   7:      PrivateBinPathProbe = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
   8:      ConfigurationFile = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile
   9:  };
  10:   
  11:  Evidence evidence = new Evidence(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence);
  12:  AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(name, evidence, setup);
```

Seems very simple, but because “ApplicationBase” is different from “AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory” we ran into what seems to be a very well know exception.

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Host.Services, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

If you have worked with any sort of dynamically loading assemblies I am fairly sure that is familiar to you. And the issue is that “Host.Services” was know within the Host Application Domain because it is stored in “C:\Program Files\My App”, and the Application Domain looking for it is looking in “C:\My Plug-ins”.

Well we Thought we instructed it to also look in “AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory” which would be “C:\Program Files\My App”, but that was not the case.

AppDomain.AssemblyResolve to the rescue?
Ok so we have been working with these quirks before, so we knew how we could use “AppDomain.AssemblyResolve” to manually resolve any assemblies that the AppDomain it self could not handle.

```
1:  string applicationBase = Path.GetDirectoryName(interOperabilityPackageType.AssemblyDescription.AssemblyPath);
   2:  AppDomainSetup setup = new AppDomainSetup
   3:  {
   4:      ApplicationName = name,
   5:      ApplicationBase = applicationBase,
   6:      PrivateBinPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
   7:      PrivateBinPathProbe = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
   8:      ConfigurationFile = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile
   9:  };
  10:   
  11:  Evidence evidence = new Evidence(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence);
  12:  AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(name, evidence, setup);
  13:  domain.AssemblyResolve += Resolve;
```

That should work right, well we thought so and ones again we were wrong, what happens now is that instead of actually getting as far as initializing the Application Domain and using it, instead it fails right where we hooked up the event handler for resolving assemblies.

Again the exception looks very much like the previous mentioned, but this time it can’t find the Assembly that contains the Type that has the “Resolve” handler we set up in the very last line in the above snippet.

AppDomain.Load then!
Ok, so obviously when hooking up the event handler, the Application Domain needs to know the Type of the object handling that event, that is actually fairly understandable when you think about it, so if the Application Domain can’t even find that one and load we can’t really handle anything.

So what is next? Our idea was to manually instruct the Application Domain to load a shallow assembly that didn’t have any other dependencies that what could be found in the GAC, and the hook an event handler up.

```
 1:  string applicationBase = Path.GetDirectoryName(interOperabilityPackageType.AssemblyDescription.AssemblyPath);
   2:  AppDomainSetup setup = new AppDomainSetup
   3:  {
   4:      ApplicationName = name,
   5:      ApplicationBase = applicationBase,
   6:      PrivateBinPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
   7:      PrivateBinPathProbe = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
   8:      ConfigurationFile = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile
   9:  };
  10:   
  11:  Evidence evidence = new Evidence(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence);
  12:  AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(name, evidence, setup);
  13:  domain.Load(File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Host.AssemblyLoader.dll")));
  14:  domain.AssemblyResolve += new AssemblyLoader(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory).Handle;
```

Using a very simple little class like the following, and don’t mind the odd Resolve behavior.

```
 1:  [Serializable]
   2:  public class AssemblyLoader
   3:  {
   4:      private string ApplicationBase { get; set; }
   5:   
   6:      public AssemblyLoader(string applicationBase)
   7:      {
   8:          ApplicationBase = applicationBase;
   9:      }
  10:   
  11:      public Assembly Resolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
  12:      {
  13:          AssemblyName assemblyName = new AssemblyName(args.Name);
  14:          string fileName = string.Format("{0}.dll", assemblyName.Name);
  15:          return Assembly.LoadFile(Path.Combine(ApplicationBase, fileName));
  16:      }
  17:  }
```

So yes or no?… NO!… same problem still.

Things are much more simple!
Actually things became much more simple in the end when we managed to make it work.

I Can’t say how exactly the .NET team has envisioned that this should work, we couldn't really find out any useable things that the “PrivateBinPath” and “PrivateBinPathProbe” was used for. Well we use them now, and made them work as we expected they would!

So we changed the “AssemblyLoader” class to look like this instead:

```
   1:  [Serializable]
   2:  public class AssemblyLoader : MarshalByRefObject
   3:  {
   4:      private string ApplicationBase { get; set; }
   5:   
   6:      public AssemblyLoader()
   7:      {
   8:          ApplicationBase = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.PrivateBinPath;
   9:          AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += Resolve;
  10:      }
  11:   
  12:      private Assembly Resolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
  13:      {
  14:          AssemblyName assemblyName = new AssemblyName(args.Name);
  15:          string fileName = string.Format("{0}.dll", assemblyName.Name);
  16:          return Assembly.LoadFile(Path.Combine(ApplicationBase, fileName));
  17:      }
  18:  }
```

So rather than hooking up the event where we created the Application Domain, we let the class do it by it self, and to “CurrentDomain” instead.

Ok so wait, doesn’t that cause an issue when creating it in the factory since it is now loading for the wrong domain? Well thankfully you are able to create objects within domains from the outside.

So creating the domain is now done as follows:

```
1:  string applicationBase = Path.GetDirectoryName(interOperabilityPackageType.AssemblyDescription.AssemblyPath);
   2:  AppDomainSetup setup = new AppDomainSetup
   3:  {
   4:      ApplicationName = name,
   5:      ApplicationBase = applicationBase,
   6:      PrivateBinPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
   7:      PrivateBinPathProbe = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
   8:      ConfigurationFile = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile
   9:  };
  10:   
  11:  Evidence evidence = new Evidence(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence);
  12:  AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(name, evidence, setup);
  13:  domain.CreateInstanceFrom(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Host.AssemblyLoader.dll"),"Host.AssemblyLoader");
```

We don’t even care for maintaining a reference to the “AssemblyLoader” since it should pretty much be kept alive by hooking it self up to the Event.

Hopefully this can help some that has stumbled over the same problem, I see many workarounds where people then either just let Plug-ins be installed in same host directory, having all the necessary dependencies deployed along with the plug-in even though it isn’t something the plug-in knows it is dependant on and so forth.

The above at least enables us to install plug-ins away from our host application base which I think is nice.

If anyone have solved this differently, then please make a response, maybe we can find pros and cons in either way, or just discover a better solution.

If you have any questions or can’t get the above to work, then feel free to ask.

author: Jens Melgaard | posted @ Thursday, July 01, 2010 3:08 PM | Feedback (0)

Comment: PrivateBinPathProbe is not meant to be a directory, but instead a way to indicate that the privatebinpath should be probed. You should use this like a bool. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomainsetup.privatebinpathprobe%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Is there any reason why you do not use the original assemblies ?

So unless your foreign appdomain uses credentials that prevent it from accessing the original assemblies, the method AppDomain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap is capable of doing so.

I suggest you isolate your remotely executed code in a MarshalByRefObject class, using a class like this :

```
public class MyRemoteClass : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public void SetupLogging()
    { 
       // ...
    }
}
```

And use it like this :

```
var assemblyPath = new Uri(typeof(MyRemoteClass).Assembly.CodeBase).LocalPath;
var remote = (MyRemoteClass)domain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(assemblyPath, "NameSpace.MyRemoteClass");

remote.SetupLogging();
```

This will avoid the unnecessary trouble of passing return values via appdomain state, as DoCallBack does not return values. This will also avoid mixing AppDomain plumbing code with your application logic.

Finally, you may need to intercept AppDomain.AssemblyResolve inside MyRemoteClass for other dependencies to load properly, though.

Comment: The problem is that you can only load assemblies that are defined under your "ApplicationBase" and the two appdomains have completely different ApplicationBase values..

Comment: this is the right way to execute a method in another appdomain

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution after loading the assembly from byte setting the .GetName().CodeBase to null resolved the problem...

After looking around i found [this](http://dotjem.com/archive/2010/07/01/39.aspx) page and it has a better solution then mine!

Comment: Hmm somehow this stopped working even after assigning it null it still has it's original value

Comment: The link doesn't work anymore. I guess that's why its recommended that the solution is pasted here, besides leaving a link.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aehss7y0.aspx the behaviour of `AppDomain.CreateDomain` has changed with .NET4 and you should use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130766.aspx and setup `Evidence` and `grants` "manually"...

Comment: Thanks a lot for the heads up, but that should have been a comment not a answer as it has nothing to do with why it didn't work...

Answer (score 0):

If you need to load assembly yourself avoid loading from bytes... I'd recommend to use at least loading by full assembly path.

In general to investigate problems with loading assemblies serach for "fusion log viewer" ( http://www.bing.com/search?q=fussion+log+viewer ) and use the tool to see where code tries to load assemblies from.

Comment: The problem is that you can only load assemblies that are defined under your "ApplicationBase" and the two appdomains have completely different ApplicationBase values..

Answer (score 0):

My educated guess is that you missed an important part of the error message:

System.IO.FileNotFoundException was unhandled Message=Could not load file or
assembly 'TaskExecuter, Version=1.0.4244.31921, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
**or one of its dependencies**. The system cannot find the file specified. Source=mscorlib

Besides not being able to load your assembly from another location than under your ApplicationBase there is probably some dependend assembly missing from where it could be resolved and loaded.

By the way, if you start loading from bytes you should have a look at the assemblies loaded to your domain. The dependend assembly might be loaded already, but the dependency cannot be resolved automatically. If you have the same assembly loaded twice, its types will be incompatible. You'll get funny CastExceptions saying an object of YourClass cannot be cast to YourClass.

You can try to register an AssemblyResolve event handler to your domain, but with this you end up easily with some black magic conjuring stuff from .dll hell.
If everything else fails and you go to .dll hell yourself, meet me here:
[Need to hookup AssemblyResolve event when DisallowApplicationBaseProbing = true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11122052/need-to-hookup-assemblyresolve-event-when-disallowapplicationbaseprobing-true/19702548#19702548)