# How do I use AppDomain.CreateDomain with AssemblyResolve?

Tags: c#, oop, c#-4.0, applicationdomain

I want to load my assemblies from WCF by using memory. Everything is working good WHEN:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve);
Assembly[] assBefore = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
foreach (byte[] binary in deCompressBinaries)
    loadedAssembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(binary);
```

But I want to use AppDomain.CreateDomain, not the current domain:

```
protected void LoadApplication()
{
    this.ApplicationHost = AppDomain.CreateDomain("TestService", null, new AppDomainSetup
    {
        ApplicationBase = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase
    });

    ApplicationHost.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(OnAssemblyResolve);
    foreach (AssemblyName asmbly in System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies())
    {
        ApplicationHost.Load(asmbly);
    }
    List<byte[]> deCompressBinaries = new List<byte[]>();
    foreach (var item in AppPackage.Item.AssemblyPackage)
        deCompressBinaries.Add(item.Buffer);
    var decompressvalues =  DeCompress(deCompressBinaries);
    deCompressBinaries.Clear();
    deCompressBinaries = decompressvalues.ToList();

    foreach (byte[] binary in deCompressBinaries)
        ApplicationHost.Load(binary);

    Assembly[] assAfter = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
}

Assembly OnAssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    return Assembly.Load(args.Name);
}
```

I have two class libraries, ClassLibrary1 and ClassLibrary2 using the below:

```
namespace ClassLibrary2
{
    public class Class1 : MarshalByRefObject
    {
        public Class1()
        {

        }

        public int GetSum(int a , int b)
        {
            try
            {
                ClassLibrary1.Class1 ctx = new ClassLibrary1.Class1();
                return ctx.Sum(a, b);
            }
            catch
            {
                return -1;
            }
        }

        public int GetMultiply(int a, int b)
        {
            return a * b;
        }
    }
}
```

Classlibrary2 depends on ClassLibrary1. So I am using assemblyresolver. But I get an error on **ApplicationHost.Load(binary);**:

> Error: **Could not load file or assembly 'ClassLibrary1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.**

Also it is NOT FIRING ASSEMBLYRESOLVER. My cursor is not going to  the Assemblyresolver method. How do I use AppDomain.CreateDomain with the resolve method?

Comment: There is an exact duplicate of this QA: http://www.rqna.net/qna/mqpzvv-how-to-use-appdomain-createdomain-with-assemblyresolve.html WTF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally don't like loading assemblies from a byte array. I think it is better to save your assemblies to a temporary folder and then load them from that folder. Take a look at this article: *[Application Domains is hard…](http://dotjem.com/archive/2010/07/01/39.aspx)*.

Comment: The link is broken: "`Server Error in '/' Application. The resource cannot be found. Description: HTTP 404.`"

Comment: every link is broken... =/ Have anyone figured it out?

Comment: @JobaDiniz, someone reposted this blog entry in this SO answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/23689445/880156.