# why AssemblyResolve not working?

Tags: c#, .net, plugins, appdomain

i really wonder why assemblyResolver not working? Also i can not use

**foreach (byte[] binary in deCompressBinaries)

            ApplicationHost.Load(binary);**

how to fire AssemblyResolve? please look my reference question:  **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9721686/how-to-use-appdomain-createdomain-with-assemblyresolve**

```
    protected void LoadApplication()
    {

        AppDomainSetup domainSetup = new AppDomainSetup();
        domainSetup.ApplicationBase = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        domainSetup.DisallowBindingRedirects = false;
        domainSetup.DisallowCodeDownload = true;
        domainSetup.LoaderOptimization = LoaderOptimization.SingleDomain;
        //domainSetup.ConfigurationFile = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile;
        ApplicationHost = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Test.Service", null, domainSetup);
        object obj = ApplicationHost.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap("Test.Process", "Test.ApplicationLoader");

        Assembly objExecutingAssemblies = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        AssemblyName[] arrReferencedAssmbNames = objExecutingAssemblies.GetReferencedAssemblies();

        foreach (AssemblyName assName in arrReferencedAssmbNames)
        {
            ApplicationHost.Load(assName);
        }


        ApplicationHost.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(OnAssemblyResolve);

        List<byte[]> deCompressBinaries = new List<byte[]>();
        foreach (var item in AppPackage.Item.AssemblyPackage)
            deCompressBinaries.Add(item.Buffer);
        var decompressvalues =  DeCompress(deCompressBinaries);
        deCompressBinaries.Clear();
        deCompressBinaries = decompressvalues.ToList();

        foreach (byte[] binary in deCompressBinaries)
            ApplicationHost.Load(binary);

        Assembly[] assAfter = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
    }

    Assembly OnAssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
    {
        return Assembly.Load(args.Name);
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to use AppDomain.CreateDomain with AssemblyResolve?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9721686/how-to-use-appdomain-createdomain-with-assemblyresolve)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `AssemblyResolve` will never fire, because you're loading up all the assemblies in the `LoadApplication` method - `AssemblyResolve` will only be called if the required assembly reference fails to be resolved.

I would suggest running [fuslogvw.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) so that you can visualize what is going on.

If you want to load the assemblies on an as-needed basis, the block of code:

```
List<byte[]> deCompressBinaries = new List<byte[]>();
foreach (var item in AppPackage.Item.AssemblyPackage)
deCompressBinaries.Add(item.Buffer);
var decompressvalues =  DeCompress(deCompressBinaries);
deCompressBinaries.Clear();
deCompressBinaries = decompressvalues.ToList();

foreach (byte[] binary in deCompressBinaries)
    ApplicationHost.Load(binary);

Assembly[] assAfter = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
```

will need to be worked into the `AssemblyResolve`. The block currently loads EVERYTHING into the AppDomain, so you'd have to rework that piece of logic.

Of course, the other thing you might want do is not to re-invent the wheel, and use [ILMerge](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=17630).

Answer (score 2):

*AssemblyResolve* fill fire only of CLR is failed to load an assembly by one of the reasons. This event will not fire just because you loading your assemblies from byte array.

Here are some examples.

- This code **will** fire *AssemblyResolve* event, because "System.Drawing" as an assembly name is not sufficient.

  ```
  object obj2 = ApplicationHost.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap("System.Drawing", "System.Drawing.Rectangle");
  ```
- This code **will not** fire *AssemblyResolve* event, because "System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" is a fully qualified assembly name.

  ```
  object obj2 = ApplicationHost.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap("System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", "System.Drawing.Rectangle");
  ```